# Counting how many fields are the same in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table organised as follows:

```
ID, name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6
```

Sample data

```
select ID, name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6
from datatable

123, bob, mark, jane, bob, jane, fred  
124, mark, mark, mark, bob, bob, bob
```

and I need to end up with something like

```
123, bob,  2  
123, mark, 1  
123, jane, 2  
123, fred, 1  
124, mark, 3  
124, bob,  3
```

Where the count is the number of times a name appears in the record. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @tbl table (ID int, name1 varchar(10), name2 varchar(10), name3 varchar(10), name4 varchar(10), name5 varchar(10), name6 varchar(10))
insert into @tbl values
(123, 'bob', 'mark', 'jane', 'bob', 'jane', 'fred'),  
(124, 'mark', 'mark', 'mark', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob')

select id, [name], count(*) cnt from (
    select ID, name1 [name] from @tbl
    union all
    select ID, name2 from @tbl
    union all
    select ID, name3 from @tbl
    union all
    select ID, name4 from @tbl
    union all
    select ID, name5 from @tbl
    union all
    select ID, name6 from @tbl
) a group by id, [name]
```

Comment: Thanks for all your responses, the reason the data is like that is that it is fed from another system like that and i have no access to re-write the extract

Answer (score 1):

The real reason you're having a problem here is because you have de-normalised data. Instead of 6 Name columns, you should have 1 column (called `[Name]`) and then another column to denote the "number" (ID?).

You can do this on  the fly, however, using `VALUES` to Unpivot your data, and then perform a `COUNT`, but I **strongly** recommend you fix your table design in the long run:

```
SELECT DT.ID,
       V.[Name],
       COUNT(V.[Name]) AS Names
FROM dbo.DataTable DT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DT.name1),DT.(name2),(DT.name3),(DT.name4),(DT.name5),(DT.name6))V([Name])
GROUP BY DT.ID,
         V.[Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a union approach:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, name1 AS name FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, name2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, name3 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, name4 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, name5 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, name6 FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    ID,
    name,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    ID,
    name
ORDER BY
    ID,
    name;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Doesn't 6 scans of `yourTable` seem a bit overkill?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, it's ugly, but then again the OP should ideally redesign its table to tall format instead of the current unnormalized wide format.  I don't have a problem with running the above query once, to fix things.  For frequent use, yes, it's not very performant.

Comment: *"the OP should ideally redesign its table to tall format instead"* this I am in complete agreement with.